# iPhone UIPickerViewModel Multiple components

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have set a picker's model to a custom class which inherits UIPickerViewModel

I can get the picker to display the first component's data (there are 2) but I don't see a way to tell the picker what the values are for the second column?

I'm using MontoTouch.net , but Obj-C answers are fine.

```
   override GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView pickerView, int component)
```

This doesn't let me specify the data for the 2nd column like I could when using a datasource and delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the GetComponentCount method and return 2 in that case.   You want something like:

```
public override int GetComponentCount (UIPickerView pickerView)
{
     return 2;
}

public override int GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView pickerView, int component)
{
     // component will be 0 or 1:
     return values [component].Length;
}
```